# Twitter Bootstrap Alpha 4.0 - 404/403 Response from CDNs in MS Edge

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, cdn, microsoft-edge

So I was wondering why I was getting the following responses back (404/403) when using Twitter Bootstrap Alpha 4.0 from either MaxCDN or CDNjs in the Microsoft Edge browser.

[image]

Other notes:
 - This only happens in MS Edge, all other modern browsers don't return this
 - This only seems to happen with the CSS files, not the Bootstrap JS
 - This happens both locally and when published

I am simply loading it in the `<head>` as usual:

```
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

**UPDATE:**

There is also a post discussing this same issue here:
[66 Edge errors: HTTP403 FORBIDDEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34381601/66-edge-errors-http403-forbidden?lq=1)

Comment: same issue for our super simple website linking `<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha256-7s5uDGW3AHqw6xtJmNNtr+OBRJUlgkNJEo78P4b0yRw= sha512-nNo+yCHEyn0smMxSswnf/OnX6/KwJuZTlNZBjauKhTK0c+zT+q5JOCx0UFhXQ6rJR9jg6Es8gPuD2uZcYDLqSw==" crossorigin="anonymous">`  only on edge

Comment: I've just discovered exact same issue. Are you using CDN?

Comment: Yes, we are using cdn resources like I have stated in the original question. Maxcdn and cdnjs

Answer (score 1):

As long as there is no fix, you can use 3.3.5 which (as opposed to the current 3.3.6) doesn't have that bug.

Answer (score 0):

In testing this myself I could not get it to work in any browser unless I changed it to HTTPS . Using the following code worked in all browsers for me

```
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: Unfortunately, didn't work for me. Specifically setting the protocol to "http" or "https" returned the same responses. I'm guessing it's just something that needs to be fixed with the files themselves.

Comment: That is odd as it should definitely work. Would you mind posting the entire html for your page? Also, do you have any type of external firewall that might be blocking that url?

Comment: Just to clarify, I am still able to load the files and see the website render properly. Everything works. It's just these network responses that another developer noticed in Edge's developer tools. As for the firewall, no I don't think so. We loaded TWBS version 3 from the same CDN with no issues in Edge. I would post a link, but our staging site is currently down at the moment. It's not a deal breaker, I can also load these resources locally for now.

Comment: Did you buy chance find a reason for this?   I'm getting the same issues using Bootstrap 3.3.6....