# 66 Edge errors: HTTP403 FORBIDDEN

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, http-status-code-403, microsoft-edge

```
HTTP403: FORBIDDEN - The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.
(XHR): GET - https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/less/normalize.less

HTTP403: FORBIDDEN - The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.
(XHR): GET - https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/less/print.less

HTTP403: FORBIDDEN - The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.
(XHR): GET - https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/dist/css/bootstrap.css

HTTP403: FORBIDDEN - The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.
(XHR): GET - https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/less/glyphicons.less

HTTP403: FORBIDDEN - The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.
(XHR): GET - https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/less/scaffolding.less

HTTP403: FORBIDDEN - The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.
(XHR): GET - https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/less/mixins/vendor-prefixes.less

HTTP403: FORBIDDEN - The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.
(XHR): GET - https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/less/mixins/image.less

HTTP403: FORBIDDEN - The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.
(XHR): GET - https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/less/mixins/tab-focus.less

HTTP403: FORBIDDEN - The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.
(XHR): GET - https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/less/type.less

HTTP403: FORBIDDEN - The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.
(XHR): GET - https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/less/mixins/background-variant.less

HTTP403: FORBIDDEN - The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.
(XHR): GET - https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/less/mixins/text-emphasis.less

HTTP403: FORBIDDEN - The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.
(XHR): GET - https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/less/mixins/text-overflow.less

HTTP403: FORBIDDEN - The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.
(XHR): GET - https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/less/code.less

HTTP403: FORBIDDEN - The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.
(XHR): GET - https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/less/grid.less

HTTP403: FORBIDDEN - The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.
(XHR): GET - https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/less/mixins/grid.less

HTTP403: FORBIDDEN - The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.
(XHR): GET - https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/less/mixins/grid-framework.less

HTTP403: FORBIDDEN - The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.
(XHR): GET - https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/less/tables.less

HTTP403: FORBIDDEN - The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.
(XHR): GET - https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/less/mixins/table-row.less

HTTP403: FORBIDDEN - The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.
(XHR): GET - https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/less/forms.less

HTTP403: FORBIDDEN - The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.
(XHR): GET - https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/less/mixins/forms.less

HTTP403: FORBIDDEN - The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.
(XHR): GET - https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/less/mixins/buttons.less

HTTP403: FORBIDDEN - The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.
(XHR): GET - https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/less/mixins/opacity.less

HTTP403: FORBIDDEN - The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.
(XHR): GET - https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/less/buttons.less

HTTP403: FORBIDDEN - The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.
(XHR): GET - https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/less/dropdowns.less

HTTP403: FORBIDDEN - The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.
(XHR): GET - https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/less/mixins/nav-divider.less

HTTP403: FORBIDDEN - The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.
(XHR): GET - https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/less/mixins/reset-filter.less

HTTP403: FORBIDDEN - The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.
(XHR): GET - https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/less/button-groups.less

HTTP403: FORBIDDEN - The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.
(XHR): GET - https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/less/mixins/border-radius.less

HTTP403: FORBIDDEN - The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.
(XHR): GET - https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/less/input-groups.less

HTTP403: FORBIDDEN - The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.
(XHR): GET - https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/less/navs.less

HTTP403: FORBIDDEN - The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.
(XHR): GET - https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/less/navbar.less

HTTP403: FORBIDDEN - The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.
(XHR): GET - https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/less/component-animations.less

HTTP403: FORBIDDEN - The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.
(XHR): GET - https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/less/mixins/nav-vertical-align.less

HTTP403: FORBIDDEN - The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.
(XHR): GET - https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/less/breadcrumbs.less

HTTP403: FORBIDDEN - The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.
(XHR): GET - https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/less/utilities.less

HTTP403: FORBIDDEN - The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.
(XHR): GET - https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/less/pagination.less

HTTP403: FORBIDDEN - The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.
(XHR): GET - https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/less/mixins/pagination.less
HTTP403: FORBIDDEN - The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.
(XHR): GET - https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/less/pager.less

HTTP403: FORBIDDEN - The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.
(XHR): GET - https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/less/labels.less

HTTP403: FORBIDDEN - The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.
(XHR): GET - https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/less/mixins/labels.less

HTTP403: FORBIDDEN - The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.
(XHR): GET - https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/less/badges.less

HTTP403: FORBIDDEN - The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.
(XHR): GET - https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/less/jumbotron.less

HTTP403: FORBIDDEN - The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.
(XHR): GET - https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/less/alerts.less

HTTP403: FORBIDDEN - The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.
(XHR): GET - https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/less/thumbnails.less

HTTP403: FORBIDDEN - The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.
(XHR): GET - https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/less/mixins/alerts.less

HTTP403: FORBIDDEN - The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.
(XHR): GET - https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/less/progress-bars.less

HTTP403: FORBIDDEN - The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.
(XHR): GET - https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/less/mixins/gradients.less

HTTP403: FORBIDDEN - The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.
(XHR): GET - https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/less/mixins/progress-bar.less

HTTP403: FORBIDDEN - The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.
(XHR): GET - https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/less/media.less

HTTP403: FORBIDDEN - The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.
(XHR): GET - https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/less/list-group.less

HTTP403: FORBIDDEN - The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.
(XHR): GET - https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/less/panels.less

HTTP403: FORBIDDEN - The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.
(XHR): GET - https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/less/mixins/list-group.less

HTTP403: FORBIDDEN - The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.
(XHR): GET - https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/less/mixins/panels.less

HTTP403: FORBIDDEN - The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.
(XHR): GET - https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/less/responsive-embed.less

HTTP403: FORBIDDEN - The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.
(XHR): GET - https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/less/wells.less

HTTP403: FORBIDDEN - The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.
(XHR): GET - https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/less/close.less

HTTP403: FORBIDDEN - The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.
(XHR): GET - https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/less/modals.less

HTTP403: FORBIDDEN - The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.
(XHR): GET - https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/less/tooltip.less

HTTP403: FORBIDDEN - The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.
(XHR): GET - https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/less/mixins/reset-text.less

HTTP403: FORBIDDEN - The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.
(XHR): GET - https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/less/popovers.less

HTTP403: FORBIDDEN - The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.
(XHR): GET - https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/less/carousel.less

HTTP403: FORBIDDEN - The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.
(XHR): GET - https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/less/mixins/clearfix.less

HTTP403: FORBIDDEN - The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.
(XHR): GET - https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/less/mixins/center-block.less

HTTP403: FORBIDDEN - The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.
(XHR): GET - https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/less/mixins/hide-text.less

HTTP403: FORBIDDEN - The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.
(XHR): GET - https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/less/responsive-utilities.less

HTTP403: FORBIDDEN - The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.
(XHR): GET - https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/less/mixins/responsive-visibility.less
```

66 very interesting errors in Edge browser, other browsers don't have this problem. Im not sure what triggers it and everything is about Bootstrap.

---

Errorcode from Microsoft console errors table:

> HTTP403 - FORBIDDEN - The server understood the request, but is
>   refusing to fulfill it.

What's going on? What could cause this?

---

### Update

As some of you kind people pointed out, Bootstrap CDN does not have .less which seems to be the problem in here.

**But..** Im not using .less, only pure CSS. I checked all my includes and main.css that loads 3rd party stylesheets and there's no reference to .less at all.

Comment: Are you working on a localhost and even though you received these errors, did the LESS files still become accessible?

Comment: No, online site and everything was 100% working while I recieved these errors in Edge (l didn't enqueue it 2 times, I checked everything at least 10 times). Errors disappeard when I downloaded Bootstrap CSS and included it to my main.css. I hope to get it fixed in order to use cdn again but I did find only 1 unanswered post with same problem after hours of searching..

Comment: Hey @Solo, Justin from BootstrapCDN here.  We don't host any of the .less files.  Just CSS and JS.

Comment: @jdorfman How do I "disable" this? Im not requesting any .less.

Comment: I get the same error when I include 3.3.6. Using 3.3.5 gives me no errors.

Comment: @Solo can you pastebin or gist `main.css`?

Comment: @jdorfman I did a lot of research and I've discovered that `@media` is using `.less`. What options do I have? Change every `@media` to CSS3 `@media screen and` **or** include .less to my server?

Comment: i also posted this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33533605/twitter-bootstrap-alpha-4-0-404-403-response-from-cdns-in-ms-edge

Comment: Why does `@media` need .less? @media is not a construct of LESS, but CSS3: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media.

Comment: @huertanix [LINK](http://getbootstrap.com/css/) Quote from there: _We use the following media queries in our Less files to create the key breakpoints in our grid system._ I still haven't fixed this issue and Im probably still missing something in my `CSS` that is using Bootstrap `.less`. It would be so great if there was a list of Bootstrap `.less` selectors somewhere.. Im 99% sure if all these are eliminated, Bootstrap stops trying to retrieve `.less`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the LESS files are not available in the CDN.

Maybe other browsers manage to hide this error ?

Here is the result in chrome for instance :

[image]

Be sure to only use the CSS and JS files from bootstrap or host the less versions yourself. :)

Comment: The funny thing is that Im using only pure CSS and I enqueue like that: wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css', null, null ); and wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap', '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), null, true ); How to disable loading less? What am I missing?

Comment: Interesting Etienne, I'll have to look into this to see if it's the culprit, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I haven't figured out which 3.3.6 package makes no reference to Less files.  But the following steps worked for me.  To remove the errors from the console in IE Edge, or any browser for that matter, simply download the ["Source Code" package from Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/) and at the very least, make sure to reference the **less** and **dist** folders from that package, under your Bootstrap css folder.  Bootstrap will take care of the rest and you will no longer see the errors in IE edge.

As already mentioned on this page, don't use the CDN links.  My current `<head>` setup looks like this in my `<head>` area...

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
```

With a folder structure like so...

```
css
  less  
  dist
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I got this with an Angular site hosted using AWS CloudFront - doing this requires redirecting 403 and 404 to /index.html to make Angular routing work.

This works, however to get it to work in Edge you need to override the response code to 200 for the 403 and 404 redirects.